# Replacing specific letters in a String with a number and output to a new string using a for-loop

Tags: javascript, string

*Preface* - Not a homework assignment but self teaching so welcome all answers.

Goal - Replace `a=4`, `e=3`, `i=1`, `o=0` in current string and return in a new string

*Breakdown*

Things I have tried are a variation of `replace()`, `parseINT`

Replace method - should and can I write a regEx that can replace all 4 letters.  So far I can only get one at a time.

```
var input = "apples are awesome";
var output = input.replace("a","4");
4pples 4re 4wesome
```

Also tried a for loop and split the string into an arrary - but still lost.

```
var input = "apples are awesome".split();
var output = "";

for(var i =0; i < input.length: i++) {
if(input[i] === a||e||i||o) {
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`String.protoype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with regex pattern, and replacement function:

```js
var input = "apples are awesome";
var lettersMap = { a: 4, e: 3, i: 1, o: 0 };

var output = input.replace(/[aeio]/gi, function(letter) { // find all selected letters in the string and ignore case
  return lettersMap[letter.toLowerCase()]; // change all found letters to lower case and get their value from the map
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add more info to the already awesome answers provided here, you should not split your string into an array and then process the array, this is overkill and prone to errors. A RegEx is a better approach, as suggested earlier.

This will work:

```
input.replace(/a/g, 4)
```

The `/ /` is your RegEx, the letter 'a' between them `/a/` is the text to match, and the 'g' at the end `/a/g` means 'greedy' matching, in other words, "keep replacing letters in the string and don't stop just on the first one". The "stop only on the first one" is called lazy matching. Check http://javascript.info/tutorial/greedy-and-lazy for more info on this both RegEx flags.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for people like me who are not regEx'ers..

Here is a javascript version..

```js
var replace = { a: 4, e: 3, i: 1, o: 0 };
var input = "apples are awesome";

var txt = input.split('').reduce(function (a,b) {
  var rep = replace[b];
  return a + (rep !== undefined ? rep : b);
},'');

console.log(txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it, though not the best.

```js
 var input = "apples are awesome";
var output = input.replace(/a/g,'4').replace(/e/g,'3').replace(/i/,"1").replace(/o/,'0');
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use map() function :

```js
var input = "apples are awesome";
var output = input.split("").map(x => {
    switch (x) {
      case "a":
             return 4;
      case "e":
             return 3;
      case "i":
             return 1;
      case "o": 
             return 0;
      default :
             return x;
    }
 }).join("");
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Just a note::  Place this inside a snippet, you won't need to do the comment then either, as people can just run your snippet and see the answer..

Comment: @Keith Thanks a lot I didn't know this functionality. So Ive just edited this way. And that works kool !!